# Is using a HTML required attribute on an input considered validation?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, required

Im currently working on a register form, and I decided to add some required fields, like email, password etc..

The only validation i want to do on the required fields is simply not null, so i used the required attribute inside of an input element.

Is this safe? Or do i need to use additional PHP validation?

Comment: You ALWAYS need server side validation

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just realised you can simply edit the source code.. :)

Comment: @mplungjan would you mind adding your comment as an answer so I can select it as one?

Comment: @S.terKeurs It's ok. It is not really necessary to accept my comment as answer. Yes, edit the code or not use the code at all, just send POSTs using CURL etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A server side validation is better (if we can't even say needed), and it's really easy to make.**

Here's an example if needed :

```
if(!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    //Prevent SQL injection (if you use DB here)
    $pseudo = addslashes($_POST['pseudo']);
    $password = addslashes($_POST['password']);
}
```

*`addslashes()` isn't the best way but work on any DB engine, for example it's better to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you have a MySQL engine.*

And the associated form :

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <label for="pseudo">Identifiant</label>
    <input type="text" name="pseudo" required>
    <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Connexion" required>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a webpage to send you a form is not the only way in form sending.

Someone can sends you forms with other devices or can skirt your required fields and send you empty data or undesirable data like PHP Injections.

You should make a server side validation.

Answer (score -2):

It might be safe, as far as the most recent browser fully support the attribute. But I don't know what happen if someone use an old version of a browser, so if you're scared about that, a PHP validation won't be too much.

If you want a good example of a registration form, just ask me in private, I'll send it to you !

Comment: Or if no browser is used

Comment: It will *never* be safe if you're just relying on client-side validation; you could use the network tab in the dev tools on any modern browser to manipulate the POST data on the fly or just write a new HTML page with a form that posts to the same URL - and that's just the simplest ways to bypass any client-side validation...

Comment: Hum, I see... Welp sorry for the bad answer :') (It's my first one here, so It will be better next time)
And also thanks you for correcting me!